# How to display HDF satellite image in real colors?

Tags: hdf

How do I display HDF satellite image in real colors as photo image ?

LoRes http://img.nsmc.org.cn/IMG_LIB/FY3C/FY3C_MERSI_GBAL_L1_YYYYMMDD_HHmm_0250M_MS.HDF/20140308/FY3C_MERSI_GBAL_L1_20140308_0305_0250M_MS.HDF.jpg

Full HiRes 357MB, use slow FREE download
https://ufile.io/uo0ha

In HDFView-3.0.0 or Igor Pro 7 (with HDF5 Browser package) I was able to display image in gray only.

Answer (score 1):

You must assign a Red, Green, Blue (RGB) color for each image band. Thus you must know your satellite bands and which one represents which 'color'.

The MERSI sensor has [20 channels](https://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/278). Wikipedia tell us that blue is from 450 to 495 nm; green from 495 to 570 and red from 620 to 750. Thus, you must do your band composition as:

- 9 (red)
- 6 (green)
- 470 (blue)

Not coincidently, those are the bands with higher spatial resolution (250 m).

You now must check your software manual in order to seen how to change the display from a single band to a 3 band false color composite.

Comment: Thank you. I just installed QGIS Desktop but don't know how to use it to be able to open HDF file and assign colors mentioned above. Short "manual" would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Layer, Add Raster Layer, select HDF file, Open, select leyers (Emissive, EV_250_RefSB_b1-b4), select WGS84 for each layer and you will see the image :-). Now you need to assign colors to Layers 2-5. Right click second layer and select Properties, Color rendering, Check Shade Color and click the field with color selection. Into HTML field enter: #00a9ff, #a3ff00, #ff0000, #610000 brown (blue, green, red and brown for layers 2-5). How to mix the layer colors together. Emissive layer is gray and layers 2-5 need to use just the RGB channel color. When I use mulitply layers the image is very dark.

Comment: just adding that (as there are many coordinate systems containing "WGS84") that you need to select the one with "EPSG:4326" :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK,
my experience with satellite imagery is limited but I played a little with the image. First, although the [website](https://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/278) says it has 20 channels I only see 10 in QGIS and SAGA while some of them are for some calibration and it is only narrow stripe.

I found there 4 bands with image. Combining bands 1,2,3 did not give any good looking image but 3,2,1 combined to RGB composite in SAGA GIS:

[image: SAGA GIS RGB composite making]

Gave me this:

[image: RGB composite result preview]

which is IMHO close to "natural look". If this is what you wanted I can upload the image somewhere and share the link with you.

Comment: It look's great, many thanks. I installed the SAGA and was able to open HDF image layers: File, Open, Select layers, Okay and Show but I don't know how to select (Load) layers in the window RGB Composite.

Comment: You load the HDF as multiple layers in SAGA and then go to Geoprocessing / Grid / Visualisation and choose RGB Composite. You will get the dialog shown above and can generate new file. Then I used right click in the left list and used "Save as image" to save it. Resulting image can be then loaded to QGIS or other tools.

Comment: you can download mine here: https://ulozto.cz/!zqW7mj355ckS/fy3c-mersi-gbal-l1-20140308-0305-0250m-ms-rgb-composite2-7z